# Where can I ask questions about conventions?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I would like to know what people would recommend for general PHP namespace rules and how to for example improve the namespace of the popular package https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/tree/master/src/Carbon to make it less redundant.

I was considering posting this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com and https://stackoverflow.com but I don't think they really fit, because there is no actual problem to be solved. Instead, it's more about recommendations and conventions.

Is there any community where I could ask this kind of question?

Comment: Code Review only reviews code the OP owns/maintains, so I don't think this would be on topic anywhere on SE.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you think this would fit to something like reddit?

Comment: That's up to Reddit, meta SO is about what's on topic here.

Comment: Cross-posting to multiple sites is definitely a bad idea, so please don't do that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did not plan to do cross-posting, I only considered of posting to one of those.

Comment: Per https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I think that would be the best site for such a question but try not to make it too open-ended. Identify a specific thing that you don't like about how your software is currently structured and ask how would the community go about deciding how to re-structure it. I don't think you are looking for someone to do this work for you but rather explain the thought process behind making better decisions, right?

Comment: What does "improve the namespace" mean? I'm sure some people would argue that your namespace is fine and tell you to shoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends very much on the specifics of question. It's not easy to give you a clear answer with the amount of detail you provide.

If by "conventions" you mean the various PSRs for the PHP ecosystem (e.g. related to namespaces you have [PSR-0](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)), we [have a bunch of questions related to those](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpsr-0%5D%20OR%20%5Bpsr-4%5D%20&mixed=0). Depending on what exactly you are asking, your question could do fine.

And there [are plenty of questions about PHP and namespaces on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bphp%5d%20AND%20%5bnamespaces%5d&mixed=0). Many of them are even good, interesting questions.

But an open-ended question like the one which seems to stem from your post here (*"what people would recommend for general PHP namespace rules and how to for example improve the namespace of..."*) would not.

A question like this would be off-topic here: Too broad and opinion based.

And as stated, I don't think would fit anywhere on the network, although the closest would probably be SE.SE. If you have **specific** question in mind you could ask in *their* meta to see if they would be OK with that.

In the end it boils down to you providing a specific question you want to ask instead of a general idea; that would make easier to determine if the what you want to ask would find a warm welcome here on SO or on a different network site.